# Basic questions about Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I just started myself self-tutoring on Docker but run into all kinds of issues. I installed Docker on a Windows 10 Home laptop and did an initial test which worked. Then I started doing this MS Learn tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-containers/ but am running into all kinds of issues. Everything went well until exercise 5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-containers/5-exercise-create-custom-docker-image
I suspect I lack some knowledge of the basics, so here are my "stupid questions":

- in Create step 3: where do I store the Dockerfile? In Build step 1:
  this command throws an error because it can't find the Dockerfile (yes, I did store it without the .txt extension)
- In Build step 1: where is the built image stored? In which directory should I build it?
- In Test step 2: In which directory should I run it?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained; people should understand them without going to these links. Links can break, or content change. When you [edit] your question, include the error messages you get and the exact steps to reproduce the errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can store the `Dockerfile` in your projects root. I don't know how the commands works, but you can simple create a new file in notepad++ and save it as `Dockerfile`. I suggest to use [Viusal Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) instead (it is free and can help you a lot).
2. The built image is stored at your docker-deamon. The image is not a file.
3. I think you mean step 1: It dosen't matter where you run `docker run -p 8080:80 -d --name reservations reservationsystem`. The image is stored in your docker-deamon. Because of this fact, you can run the command "everywhere" on your maschine (it dosen't read or create files at the working-directory).